# Can not deploy war file using Struts2 into Geronimo 2.2.1

Tags: deployment, struts2, geronimo

I try to deploy struts2-showcase.war in Struts2-2.3.1-all.zip into Geronimo 2.2.1.
Geronimo responded the below errors:

```
011-12-30 15:31:53,294 WARN  [TomcatModuleBuilder] Web application . does not contain a WEB-INF/geronimo-web.xml deployment plan.  This may or may not be a problem, depending on whether you have things like resource references that need to be resolved.  You can also give the deployer a separate deployment plan file on the command line.
Deployer operation failed: org/apache/struts/taglib/html/FormTag
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/taglib/html/FormTag
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
2011-12-30 15:31:56,608 ERROR [Deployer] Deployment failed due to 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/taglib/html/FormTag
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.classloader.JarFileClassLoader.access$200(JarFileClassLoader.java:52)
  at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.classloader.JarFileClassLoader$6.run(JarFileClassLoader.java:302)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.classloader.JarFileClassLoader.findClass(JarFileClassLoader.java:254)
  at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.MultiParentClassLoader.loadOptimizedClass(MultiParentClassLoader.java:401)
  at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(MultiParentClassLoader.java:257)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.geronimo.jasper.deployment.JspModuleBuilderExtension.parseTldFile(JspModuleBuilderExtension.java:472)
  at org.apache.geronimo.jasper.deployment.JspModuleBuilderExtension.getListenerClasses(JspModuleBuilderExtension.java:433)
  at org.apache.geronimo.jasper.deployment.JspModuleBuilderExtension.createJspClassFinder(JspModuleBuilderExtension.java:189)
  at org.apache.geronimo.jasper.deployment.JspModuleBuilderExtension.addGBeans(JspModuleBuilderExtension.java:158)
  at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.deployment.TomcatModuleBuilder.addGBeans(TomcatModuleBuilder.java:513)
  at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.SwitchingModuleBuilder.addGBeans(SwitchingModuleBuilder.java:165)
  at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.EARConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(EARConfigBuilder.java:652)
  at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:257)
  at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:136)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
  at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:130)
  at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:851)
  at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:237)
  at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.AbstractDeployCommand.doDeploy(AbstractDeployCommand.java:116)
  at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.DistributeCommand.run(DistributeCommand.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anybody tell me what's wrong with Geronimo ?
I know Geronimo told me it can not find the class:
org/apache/struts/taglib/html/FormTag object.
But, the object is belongs to Struts1, and my war file use Struts2.
I checked struts2-showcase.war and confirmed that struts2-showcase.war never uses the above object.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you try adding the other library anyway?  It may help reveal the problem.

Comment: oops. I think the war file struts2-showcase.war in Struts2-2.3.1-all.zip is too complex. I will use another case to ask question again.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Hi Sir, 
I use another simple case to post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698026/war-file-using-struts2-can-not-be-deployed-to-geronimo-2-2-1
You may go there to take a look. There will be more detail information.

Answer (score 1):

never worked with Geronimo but a quick look at the log saying that `geronimo-web.xml` in not there inside `WEB-INF` folder.

Check this thread as the person has same issue

[How to deploy in Geronimo](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@geronimo.apache.org/msg09368.html)

Have you tried running web-app? Is It working or not, i am asking these question based on the content of stack trace you have posted

Comment: I can not run the web-app because Geronimo told me it deployed failed.

I use another simple case to you at here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698026/war-file-using-struts2-can-not-be-deployed-to-geronimo-2-2-1